# nVidia + Mavericks Drivers

Tags: macos, driver, gpu

Is anyone aware of official nVidia drivers for 9x series cards and OSX Mavericks?

I'm aware of [these](http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/73628/en-us) but they only seem to support 8 series cards and I have a 9800GTX+

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the nVida site and using they driver find engine they do not have the driver, so nobody else would have it.

Comment: They do some OSX drivers, but they're not usually found through the driver engine sadly.